# Why Principled BSDF has no texture support for glossy color pass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, render-passes

During compositing I've found out lack of glossy textured color pass for *Principled BSDF* material. *Glossy BSDF* works well though.

Example pics:

**Glossy BSDF**
[image]

**Principled BSDF**
[image]

**Material**
[image]